# When ever i add spring security configuration in web.xml i get the error "No WebApplicationContext found: no ContextLoaderListener registered?"

Tags: spring, spring-security

When i add the following into web.xml

```
   <filter>
     <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
     <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
    <init-param>
         <param-name>contextAttribute</param-name>
    <param-value>org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.CONTEXT.spring</param-value>
    </init-param>
    </filter>

    <filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>
```

I am getting the following error

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: No WebApplicationContext found: no ContextLoaderListener registered?
    org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:251)
```

Could someone help me here?

Comment: missing this in your web.xml? <listener><listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class></listener>

Comment: possible duplicate of [spring security No WebApplicationContext found](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5046403/spring-security-no-webapplicationcontext-found)

Answer (score 3):

I see that you didn't attached your entire web.xml.
From the exception you got I assume you did not configure Spring IoC container which is an integral part of Spring.

You have several ways to do so, here is one way (goes in your web.xml):

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml</param-value>
</context-param>

<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>
```

You can start with an empty applicationContext.xml, here is an example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<beans
    xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:flex="http://www.springframework.org/schema/flex" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop" xmlns:security="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-2.5.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/flex
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/flex/spring-flex-1.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/security
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-3.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd
">
</beans>
```

You can read more about Spring configuration in here

[Spring IoC container](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#context-create)

Comment: This was helpful to me.  In my case, I did not need `<context-param>`, as this matched the (magical) default value in my codebase!